# Stop watch delay using timer c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, delay, stopwatch

I want to add a stopWatch to my form but the one i made is lagging behind the time of other timer in pc. Can you give any solution for that?
(My timer interval is 100).
this is my code:

```
int min, sec, ms = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time.Text = min + ":" + sec + ":" + ms.ToString();
        ms++;
        if (ms > 9)
        {
            ms = 0;
            sec++;
        }

        if (sec > 59)
        {
            sec = 0;
            min++;
        }

    }

    private void timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

It working but with easy delay. I have tried to change so many things but none of them is working..

Comment: Why not use a TimeSpan object?

Comment: I don't know how I can use it haha

Comment: Use a DateTime as suggested by EZI below, or use the [Stopwatch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class in much the same way.  You'd simply Start() it, then use the Elapsed() property in your Tick() event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timer's tick is not as precise as you think. So It would be better if you calculate the difference between start time and the time *tick* invoked.

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;  
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Time.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ff");
}

private void timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;   
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: It says there is an error in  - ToString("mm:ss"); "Format expectation was unhandled"

Comment: Its working!! :) but can i see also 2 digits of the millisecond?

Comment: @bar it is `@"mm\:ss\.ff"` But I think this is not related with your question. You can easily learn it from docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your timer interval is 100ms, so create a TimeSpan object, as a class variable, for that

```
TimeSpan _100ms = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,100);
```

Add this to your TimeSpan object that you're using to track time

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
ts = ts.Add(_100ms);
```

To display it to your UI:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ts = ts.Add(_100ms);
    Time.Text = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FLqt93)

Comment: More *.Netish* way, but the problem remains: *"but the one i made is lagging behind the time of other timer in pc"*